# Weka trained set and test set with additional classes

Tags: weka

Consider the following example:

**Train:**

```
...
@attribute FOO {a,b}
...
```

**Test:**

```
...
@attribute FOO {a,b,c}
...
```

We have a trained model against a train set in the aforementioned format. This model has already been computed using lots of data. We do not want to retrain it for the new test set to classify as it requires a remarkable computational effort.

For this reason we wonder about how can we manipulate the new test set in way of discarding this additional value for the attribute but still preserve the whole entry. What would you do? I also read about the question mark.. if we replace each 'c' with a question mark and we update the header removing the 'c' from the enum for the attribute FOO, it works but I am not very sure about its outcome.

Thank you

Comment: You may want to look up and see how your particular model handles missing values.  You may get a better sense if it is appropriate to replace the c's with question marks. http://list.waikato.ac.nz/pipermail/wekalist/2008-August/040701.html